# Proving the surface area and volume of revolution formula

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, solid-of-revolution

Title
Is there any way to prove the formula or surface area and volume of revolution of a function? The derivation of the formula I have found online does not really seem like a proof, but more like using intuition to explain it.
Thanks for your time and sorry if it is a stupid question lol

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. This is a cool problem. However, we might need some context to help us answer. Can you link the derivations you found online? What do you find unsatisfactory about them? Finally, what is your level of mathematics (what are the two recent courses you have taken)?

Comment: Hello, I am an IB student, taking Mathematics AA HL, meaning I am not into university yet. A video visualizing the concept around most derivations I found revolve around is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUzan1Ma9nE&t=417s  Although logically it makes perfect sense, I am not sure if one could call upon said logic to actually prove the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to give a derivation of the two formula. Please let me know if you find any mistakes:

The proof of surface area is to divide the volumn into frustrums on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, where the surface area is given by $$A=2\pi rl$$, where $l$ is length of slant of the frustrum, and $r=\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are radius of left and right radius. Then we parametrize $r_1=f(x_i)$, $r_2=f(x_{i-1})$, and $$l=\sqrt{1+f'(x_i^*)^2}\Delta{x}$$, where $x_i^*\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$. Let $\Delta{x}\to 0$,
$$A_i=2\pi\frac{f(x_i)+f(x_{i-1})}{2}\sqrt{1+f'(x_i^*)^2}\Delta{x}\to 2\pi f(x_i^*)\sqrt{1+f'(x_i^*)^2}\Delta{x}$$
The whole surface area $S$ is given by
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i=\int_{a}^{b}2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$$

The proof of volumes under revolution starts from the volumns of cylinders, i.e.
$$\Delta{V}=\pi y^2\Delta{x}$$ (replacing $r^2$ with $y^2$). Then the volumn is just
$$V=\lim_{\Delta{x}\to 0}\sum_{x=a}^{b}\Delta{V}=\lim_{\Delta{x}\to 0}\sum_{x=a}^{b}\pi y^2\Delta{x}=\int_{a}^{b}\pi y^2dx$$

If you want to rotate around different axis, just switch the order of the functions, like replacing $y=f(x)$ to $x=h(y)$. Hope this helps.